# Sqlite Select Query give me wrong result in android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, select-query

i want select images and video from sqlite database here i implement my query but it gives me wrong result my current date is 2014-07-15 but it provide me the 2014-07-25 date result which is wrong.

**My Query :**

```
SELECT * 
FROM myfiles 
WHERE (( Date('2014-07-15') >= startdate 
AND Date('2014-07-15') <= enddate ) 
AND ( strftime('%H:%M:%S', starttime) >= '02:09:50' 
OR  '02:09:50'  <= strftime('%H:%M:%S', endtime )) 
AND ( strftime('%H:%M:%S',timer_from) >= '02:09:50' 
OR '02:09:50' <= strftime('%H:%M:%S',timer_to )) 
OR ( strftime('%H:%M:%S',timer_from) = '00:00:00' 
OR '00:00:00' = strftime('%H:%M:%S',timer_to ))) 
AND ( Tuesday = 1 OR Everyday = 1) 
AND download = 1 
AND playlist_id = 65 
AND user_id='265' 
ORDER BY position_id ASC, subposition_id ASC
```

-> link for download this image 
http://screencast.com/t/yS4SqUDqhe

**Mysqlite Original database image**

[image]

> after executing query
>   [execute query image](http://screencast.com/t/AbCxJBWq)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following part evaluates the whole check to `true` even if the date is invalid:

```
OR ( strftime('%H:%M:%S',timer_from) = '00:00:00' OR '00:00:00' = strftime('%H:%M:%S',timer_to ))
```

That is, there's no surprise that the result contains marked row (its `timer_from = '00:00:00'` and `timer_to = '00:00:00'`).

**Update** 
Try to change `OR` to `AND` in the aforementioned query part.

**Update 2** 
Add following check to the end of your query before `ORDER BY position_id ASC, subposition_id ASC` and after `AND user_id='265'`:

```
AND (Date('2014-07-25') > startdate)
```

Comment: not getting exactly where should i change so get correct result

Comment: you can download the database from here http://expirebox.com/download/f98893748e1da189fc4436659e78bd0a.html

Comment: What is the expected result of query? Please, specify all details.

Comment: you can seee in the execute query image 16 no record no need to display other is same as

Comment: Great, glad my answer is helpful for you.